# Running a SQL query by using batch/.bat file in OracleSQL Developer for Oracle Database

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I just want to run the Insert query which is gonna take more than 10 hours to complete. I was thinking to run that by using a .bat file via OracleSqldeveloper in Oracle database. Please provide me some info on this.

I am looking for the approaches

Comment: How about good old sqlplus?

Comment: I don't have sysdba access

Comment: I'm quite sure that's not a requirement for using sqlplus

Comment: for starters don't setup a big fat GUI to startup up, you'll want a command line interface like SQLcl that you can fire off to run your insert. or...create a database job to do it - no tool required, just a little plsql and sql.